# comment awaiting moderation

Tags: comments, moderation

I use worpress 3.3.2 and there several users in my multiblog. Only registered users can leave comments, but comments must be approved by post author or administrator. When some user makes a comment every author sees notification about new comment awaiting moderation.

How can i hide notifications about comments that are awaiting moderation to other author's post? Maybe there is some plugin for this?

Answer (score 1):

No plug-in needed for this. Just open your theme files using the WordPress theme editor or via FTP. Look for the code that is being used to display the notice. It should be in the `index.php` file, maybe in a `content.php` file if your theme uses that, and in some cases it's in your `functions.php` file. It will use the exact text you're talking about so it should be easy to spot. You need to remove that or comment it out so it doesn't show. If you find it but can't remove it post it here and I'll help you out.

If you are using a public theme post the name here and I'll have a look.

Comment: i am speaking about comments showing in admin section - so theme files can't help me

Answer (score -1):

There is a plug in called Role Manager http://www.im-web-gefunden.de/wordpress-plugins/role-manager/ that can help you with that.

Comment: How ever its not a good practice to add to many plug ins in a wordpress Installation.
It can make the site slower and its harder to maintan the site with all the updates ect. 
I am sure you can get the same result with a bit of coding